# How to strip embedded video from content on category pages in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, video, categories

I have a couple of posts that have YouTube videos embedded in them. I only want the videos to show up on the full version of the post. On the category page that lists the posts, I don't want the video to appear.

Here is the site: http://tsa-watch.com/

and the full version of the post:

http://tsa-watch.com/2013/03/25/tsa-makes-double-amputee-marine-remove-prosthetic-legs-during-screening/

Here is a bit of code I use in functions.php to remove the first image from a post ONLY if it is listed on a category page:

```
function remove_first_image ($content) {
if (is_category()) {
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content, 1);
$content = preg_replace("/<object[^>]+>/i", "", $content, 1);
} return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_first_image');
```

Also, here is the loop that I am using on my index.php and category.php files:

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="votes" style="min-width:60px"><strong>VOTES:</strong><?php wdpv_vote(false); ?></div>
        <div class="alignleft" style="max-width:590px"> 
        <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="byline"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author() ?> in <?php the_category(', ') ?> <strong>:</strong> <?php comments_number( 'No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments' ); ?></div>
        <div class="excerpt">
        <?php 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
          the_post_thumbnail(array(115,115));
        } 
        ?>                  

        <?php the_content('Read more &raquo;'); ?>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>          

    <?php else : ?>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p><?php _e("Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here."); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a WordPress site I believe?

If so you need to look at editing the theme template file that is responsible for showing the preview of your post on the category pages and remove the section where it is showing images/videos from the post.

Unfortunately not knowing what theme it is you are using or what the file names are called it's hard to tell but look for a page template which has the word home or categories in it or open up the category.php from within your activated theme folder if you have them to see if you can find something related to this and comment it out to see if it fixes it.

Also try adding the following inside your custom function:

```
$content = preg_replace("/<embed[^>]+>/i", "", $content, 1);
```

Comment: It is a custom theme. I have edited my original question, above, to include the post loop for the category page.

Comment: Have you tried using $content = preg_replace("/<object[^>]+>/i", "", $content, 1); to remove the video object too?

Comment: I edited my question to show the updated function. Unfortunately, the video still shows.

Comment: apologies Cynthia. I meant to put embed instead of object. Can you please replace object with embed and try again. Apologies

Comment: $content = preg_replace("/<embed[^>]+>/i", "", $content, 1);

Comment: I actually had to strip out embed AND object, then it worked. Thanks!

Comment: A pleasure! Glad I could help! As a side note, are you aware that you have the following error on that page: Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_paging() in /home/patriot/public_html/wp-content/themes/tsa-watch/category.php on line 36

Comment: I was in the process of installing a pagination plugin when you looked :) Thanks for the fresh eyes though...